# Rich text field replaces HTML code reference with actual character in source tab in tridion component

Tags: rtf

when i enter an HTML character code reference for example &#10004; its getting converted to 
✔ in design which is correct , but also in the source tab.

We need the actual character reference code to be displayed in the source since its being used by another tool to perform certain operation.

It there anyway in achieving this ?

Comment: On the source of RTF field, it will appear as code only. Have you checked published content? Is the content rendered out in XML or HTML format?

Comment: Hi, can you specify what Tridion version this is including service pack and hotfix rollup?